# Community user new profile photo.

Tags: discussion, images, profile-page, community-user, user-profile

Browsing the forum brought me to a post where I saw the “robot” [community](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user had edited. At first, I thought this user was someone with another name until I saw their original sprite:[image]

As you can see, it does not have the stack exchange logo anymore. I assume there was either a glitch or was changed to accommodate an event. It changed back to what I believe to be the original “-1” pattern. This may have been asked already, but I found no related questions. What happened here?

Comment: This was also posted on [metase]: [Why has Community's profile picture changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367454). An SE developer Dean Ward has [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed#comment1224231_367454) that they are "working on restoring it network-wide". You can also check their [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367460/986753) there for technical details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ya it was a bug. Now the bug has been fixed as claimed over [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367460). As you can see the edit history the profile pic error has just been sorted 1 hour ago. Now you can see [community](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)'s real pic/profile pic

Comment: This is you copying and pasting the exact same answer from [this newer post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/bug-with-my-gravatar) as of this comment’s writing.

Comment: Ya mostly it is same and don't worry I feel one out of 2 will be marked as duplicate

Comment: @ “Name” You are not$$\text{ Jitendra Singh?}$$- interesting