# Bug with my gravatar?

Tags: support, bug, images, profile-page, gravatar

Recently, I noticed that when I temporarily went onto my meta profile, my nice purple avatar changed into a lime green avatar. You can believe that I did not change it. I can give time stamps if needed for when the photos were changed:[image]

When making this question it turned back into my normal avatar:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

At 10:19 am today, it changed back to my normal purple one:[image]

I suspect it is the same reason why [*community’s*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33878/community-user-new-profile-photo) did the same. My post at one point had -4 to 4 although there is already another good meta post on the phenomenon linked to the italicized link. I also remember when I joined MSE and got my own colored QR code looking gravatar. Maybe there is something the same about the lime green and purple avatar, like my used number used as the avatar generation seed, that made it change? I hope you agree. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: I seem to recall gravitars shifting several years ago, and IIRC someone explained that gravitars were not guaranteed to be the same forever.  But maybe it was just a blip then too? I don't recall.. too long

Comment: @rschwieb What is “IIRC”? It happened for just a few minutes before turning back. If you recall it from years ago, then why now? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: [Definition of IIRC](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/iirc#:~:text=IIRC%20is%20an%20internet%20abbreviation,not%20be%20100%25%20sure%20of.)

Comment: My custom icon briefly changed to a gravatar recently.  I cannot now tell whether it was July 19; but I expect it was the same bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya it was a bug. Now the bug has been fixed as claimed over [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367460). As you can see the edit history the profile pic error has just been sorted 1 hour ago. When I clicked on your photo I can see that now your purple pic is coming. Even [community](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) profile pic issue has also been sorted.

Comment: Just click on here and read the answer. You will get full details what has happened and why it happened

Comment: Jitendra are you still on MSE?