# Color change on the M.Se site.

Tags: discussion, bug, asking-questions, mobile-web, recent-activity

This is a quick question which again happened as a glitch. I was looking for questions to answer and somehow saw the “ask question” and “activity” button, on the home page and my page respectively, turn orange, the math meta colors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The interesting point here is that my previous question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/bug-with-my-gravatar) was just yesterday and was another bug.  I had been on safari remerging tabs after accidentally opening stack exchange in another safari window, but this might just be a red herring. Why did this page turn orange?

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange) your answer (it seems to be a style file may have gotten mixed up?).

Comment: (I sort of like orange, though.)

Comment: The answer is in that thread: the .css file seems to originate from StackOverflow.

Comment: Blues were little better than orange

Comment: It is also affecting the low quality review queue.

Comment: That the colors in that review queue are off: orange rather than blue?

Comment: @amWhy I agree!

Comment: blue color returned

Comment: I never had my post featured on the hot meta before. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @TymaGaidash May be my opinion but I have observed that when a moderator answers on a positive scored question, it usually becomes hot meta post.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that the background is a graph

Comment: @TymaGaidash not the logo the _back_ background, like the left hand side part where "Home" is written

Comment: @AdilMohammed [This one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/error) is even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange) your answer (it seems to be a style file may have gotten mixed up?).